# I keep getting this error in my log when trying to deploy my discord bot on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

```
2021-08-15T10:43:13.329976+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Starting process with command `node bot.js`
2021-08-15T10:43:14.069416+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-15T10:43:16.863160+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-15T10:43:16.959572+00:00 heroku[Worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785884+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785905+00:00 app[Worker.1]:       throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785905+00:00 app[Worker.1]:       ^
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785906+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785906+00:00 app[Worker.1]: TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785907+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Client._validateOptions (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:544:13)
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785907+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at new Client (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:73:10)
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785908+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Bot.initBot (/app/bot.js:33:13)
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785908+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Bot.init (/app/bot.js:26:7)
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785909+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:1148:5)
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785909+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785910+00:00 app[Worker.1]:   [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
2021-08-15T10:43:16.785910+00:00 app[Worker.1]: }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Discord JS v13 makes the switch to Discord API v9, it is now required to specify all intents your bot will be using in the Client constructor.

Example:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES],
});
```